# Changing all the input field to blue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

My Jquery code is supposed to transform all the input fields of the form borders to blue .. but it doesn't do that ...  Where did I exactly go wrong ?

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                alert('Works !');
                $('#provision:text').css('border', '2px solid blue');
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="provision">ESNList:
            <input type="text" id="ESNList" name="ESNList" size="30" />
            <br />ESN Start:
            <input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" />
            <br />ESN End:
            <input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" />
            <br />UnitName:
            <input type="text" id="STxName" name="STxName" size="30" />
            <br />Unit Model:
            <select name="STxName">
                <option value="stx2">STX2</option>
                <option value="protopak">Protopak</option>
                <option value="stm3" selected>STM3</option>
                <option value="acutec">Acutec</option>
                <option value="mmt">MMT</option>
                <option value="smartone">Trackpack</option>
                <option value="smartoneb">SmartOneB</option>
                <option value="audi">Acutec</option>
            </select>
            <br />RTU Model Type:
            <select name="rtumodel">
                <option value="globalstar">GlobalStar</option>
                <option value="both">Both</option>
                <option value="comtech">Comtech</option>
                <option value="stmcomtech">STMComtech</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: :text is no selector. Try without.

Comment: id='ESNStart' occurs twice. ID's are unique.

Comment: $('#provision input[type=text]').css('border', '2px solid blue');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct JQuery text-selector in your case:

`$('#provision input:text').css('border', '2px solid blue');`

The official API doc to the text-selector: http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/

Answer (score 4):

You need to actually query for those `<input>` nodes:

```
$('#provision input:text').css('border','2px solid blue');});
```

Comment: umm, no, he doesn't - the `input` is implicit.  It's just the space that's needed.

Comment: @Alnitak: I think for the sake of readabilty, you totally should be that explicit by also passing in the *node name*.

Comment: For readability, maybe, but that's _not_ the bug you've fixed, you did that (perhaps inadvertently) by adding the space.  From the _first line_ of the jQuery docs "_`$(':text') `allows us to select all `<input type="text">` elements_"

Comment: @Alnitak: trust me, it wasn't inadvertently. I just like to be precise on pseudo selectors.

Comment: OK, but don't forget that `:text` is a jQuery extension anyway.  It actually _can't_ match anything other than an `input` element.  Your answer as written does nothing to explain the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a space in your selector:

```
#provision :text
```

As written, it requires the `#provision` element itself to be a text input, rather than searching for a *descendant* of `#provision`.  Spaces are significant in selectors!

However, you should note that [`:text` is a jQuery extension](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/), and therefore not as fast as a native selector.

A better selector therefore would be:

```
$('#provision input[type="text"]')
```

or, to ensure that you catch nodes without an explicit `text` type (but which default to `text`):

```
$('#provision input').filter(':text')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#provision input:text').css('border', '2px solid blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should work  --  see it working  http://jsfiddle.net/LumF3/

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    alert('Works !');
                    $('#provision input:text').css('border', '2px solid blue');
                });
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `$('#provision input')` instead. You're trying to apply the border styles to text nodes inside the #provisions element.